# C++ about generic initialization in templates

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, generic-programming, function-templates

I am writing a generic function like below.

```
template<class Iterator, class T>
void foo(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
   T a;
   cout << a << endl;
   // do something with iterators
 }

 typedef vector<double>::iterator DblPtr;
 vector<double> values;
 foo< DblPtr, int>();
```

This functions prints out an undefined value for variable `a`, while if I change the initialization into

```
   ///
   T a = T()
   cout << a << endl;
   // do something with iterators
```

I can see that the initialized value is `0` as I am expecting.

If I call `T a` the variable is initialized with the default value, but if i call `T a = T()` I believe that due to optimization the copy constructor should  be called with the value of `T()` that is still the default one.

I cannot understand what is the difference behind these 2 lines and the reason why this happens?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, default initiaization of built-in types such as `int` leaves them uninitialized. Value initialization leaves them zero-initialized. As for your example

This is a default initialization:

```
 T a;
```

This is a value initialization, using [*copy initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

```
 T a = T();
```

You are right that copies can be elided here, so this has the effect of creating a single value-initialized `T` object. However, it does require that `T` be copyable or move-copyable. This is the case with built-in types, but it is a restriction to bear in mind.

The copy initialization syntax is required because this is a function declaration:

```
 T a();
```

but C++11 allows you to value-initialize like this:

```
 T a{};
```